# Storing counts of letters in an array

Tags: c

I am required to create a program that reads a file and store counts of all the letters, treating uppercase and lowercase letters the same. So far I got this:

```
FILE *input;  
int letter=0;
char words;
int typeofletter[letter];
input = fopen("greatgatsby.txt", "r");
while(fscanf(input, "%c", &words) != EOF)
{
    if ((words>='A')&&(words<='z'))
    {
       letter++;
    }
}
```

How would I store the count of each letter into an array?

Comment: Well at least you will need an array. What have you tried ? I see no indication you tried to store anything, just reading the string for now...

Comment: The zero-length array isn't going to get you very far.

Comment: **Hints:** How many different counts (integers) do you need to store? How are you going to store them? When you see a letter, how will you figure out which count to increment?

Comment: **Hints**: To turn a lower case char into an index (a=0...z=25) you can subtract `'a'` or 97 from that char. For upper case, subtract `'A'` or 65.

Comment: you should probably use `tolower()` so you're not reliant on some standard encoding

Comment: @SteveCox: if the encoding isn't ASCII, this becomes a *lot* more difficult; in this case, I'd argue that using `tolower()` is good practice because 1) it's the canonical way of converting case in 'C'; and 2) it makes the intention clear (self-documenting).

Comment: thanks for the help all, i realize i didn't put in what i've tried, but honestly i was at a lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an array of size 26 to store the data.

   ```
   int lettercount[26] = {0};
   ```
2. You can read the contents of the file character by character. Increment the letter count when you find a letter of the alphabet.

   ```
   int c;
   while ( (c = fgetc(input)) != EOF )
   {
     if ( isalpha(c) )
     {
       ++(lettercount[tolower(c)-'a']);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Good answer — using the standard facilities provided by `ctype.h` is more readable and less error-prone than manual comparisons and logic — however, I'd add a note to the effect that you have to `#include <ctype.h>` to get `isalpha()` and `tolower()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the functions/macros in `ctype.h` to diagnose and convert characters. Below, `isalpha()` is used to tell if a character is a letter or not, and `toupper()` is used to convert a lowercase letter to an uppercase letter.

Since letters in ASCII (assumed) are represented by contiguous numbers, subtracting the value of 'A' from any uppercase letter (or 'a' from any lowercase letter) will give a value between 0 and 25 which corresponds to that letter and can be used as an index into an array of letter counts.

If your character set is *not* ASCII, this becomes considerably more difficult and beyond the scope of simple programming examples.

The following is a complete working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_LETTERS (26)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int counts[N_LETTERS] = {0};
    int inchar;
    int i;

    /* We expect a filename on the command line */
    if(argc!=2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Supply a filename as an argument.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Open the file, bug out on error. */
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if( fp==NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* This is the part you're most interested in */
    while( (inchar = fgetc(fp)) != -1 ) {  /* Read chars until error or EOF */
        if( isalpha(inchar) ) {            /* Only count letters            */
            i = toupper(inchar) - 'A';     /* Convert letter to index 0-25  */
            counts[i]++;                   /* Increment count for letter    */
        }
    }

    /* Close the file */
    fclose(fp);

    /* Print out the results */
    for(i=0; i<N_LETTERS; i++) {
        printf("Count of letter '%c': %d\n", 'A'+i, counts[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This answer is _very unclear and exhibits a number of poor practices_, notably it completely avoids addressing the actual mistakes in the OP code.  If the OP is using certain forms of comparison, is it not better to address the question in the same methods?

Comment: It does nothing of the kind, and no, it's not, it's better to do it in the canonical way and explain it. Grow up.

Comment: Canonical?  Give me a _relevant_ reference that states which of our methods is canonical and which is not. The standard provides for both.  Now the question is which directly addresses the OP question?

Comment: @Emmet we came up with very similar code to answer the OP. I tested my code exactly as you did :) :) Like minds.

Answer (score 1):

You need probably this (quick and dirty, based on your version, no error checking, file not closed, not tested)

```
FILE *input;  
int letter=0;
char words;
int typeofletter[26];
input = fopen("greatgatsby.txt", "r");

while(fscanf(input, "%c", &words) != EOF)
{
   if ((words >= 'a') && (words <= 'z'))
   {
      words -= 'a'-'A' ;   // convert to up upper case
   }

   if ((words >= 'A') && (words <= 'Z'))
   {
      typeofletter[word - 'A']++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The only issue I have to point out is that Arrays are statically set and their size is set, it cannot be changed dynamically.

You'd be better using another sequential container type such as c++ vector. For example:

```
int Main(int argc, char * argc[])
{
 //.... preceding code
 FILE * OpenedFile; //Get the file and open it
 vector<char> ChrVec;

 for(/*EACH LETTER*/)
 {
   ChrVec.push_back(/*LETTERPOINTER*/ *p);
 }
}
```

Comment: This is *C*. `Main()`? `Vector<char>`?